# Can shadow under FusionTableLayer be removed or hided?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

There is a small shadow under the FusionTableLayer:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/43127331/colbert_nation/map-simple.html
(shadow is best seen where light blue is overlapping dark blue.)
Is there any way to remove or hide the shadow?

Thanks a lot,
Mari.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the polygon border color is the problem? In http://dl.dropbox.com/u/43127331/colbert_nation/map_module.js I see typos in the polygon styles:

stokeColor: '#ffffff',
stokeWeight: 1,

Should be "stroke", not "stoke", so those settings are having no effect.

Comment: thanks.I fix it now, but I still have shadow under district layer.